# How to close drop down clicking anywhere on page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```js
let el = $('.switch');
let cur = el.find('.current');
let options = el.find('.options li');
let content = $('#content');

// Open language dropdown panel
el.on('click', function(e) {
  el.addClass('show-options');
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    el.addClass('anim-options');
  }, 50);
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    el.addClass('show-shadow');
  }, 200);
});

// Close language dropdown panel
options.on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  el.removeClass('anim-options');
  el.removeClass('show-shadow');
  
  let newLang = $(this).data('lang');
  
  cur.find('span').text(newLang);
  content.attr('class', newLang);
  
  setLang(newLang);
  
  options.removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    el.removeClass('show-options');
  }, 600);
});

// Save selected options into Local Storage
function getLang() {
  let lang;
  if (localStorage.getItem('currentLang') === null) {
    lang = cur.find('span').text();
  } else {
    lang = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentLang')).toLowerCase();
  }
  
  // console.log(lang);
  cur.find('span').text(lang);
  options.parent().find(`li[data-lang="${lang}"]`).addClass('selected');
  
  content.attr('class', lang);
}

getLang();

function setLang(newLang) {
  localStorage.setItem('currentLang', JSON.stringify(newLang).toLowerCase());
  
  content.attr('class', newLang);
  
  // console.log('New language is: ' + newLang);
}
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,900|Noto+Sans:400,400i,700&subset=latin-ext");
:root {
  font-size: 100%;
  --base-font-size: calc(15px + .5vw);
  --ratio: 1.18;
  --h6: calc(var(--base-font-size) * var(--ratio));
  --h5: calc(var(--h6) * var(--ratio));
  --h4: calc(var(--h5) * var(--ratio));
  --h3: calc(var(--h4) * var(--ratio));
  --h2: calc(var(--h3) * var(--ratio));
  --h1: calc(var(--h2) * var(--ratio));
}

body {
  font-family: "Noto Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-size: var(--base-font-size);
  line-height: 1.6;
  color: #313436;
}

#content {
  max-width: 48rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
}
#content:not(.en) [data-lang=en], #content:not(.sv) [data-lang=sv]{
  display: none;
}
#content.en [data-lang=en],#content.sv [data-lang=sv]{
  display: block;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Playfair Display", "Noto Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: var(--h1);
  line-height: calc(var(--h1) * 1.2);
}

h2 {
  font-size: var(--h2);
  line-height: calc(var(--h2) * 1.2);
}

h3 {
  font-size: var(--h3);
  line-height: calc(var(--h3) * 1.3);
}

h4 {
  font-size: var(--h4);
  line-height: calc(var(--h4) * 1.3);
}

h5 {
  font-size: var(--h5);
  line-height: calc(var(--h5) * 1.4);
}

h6 {
  font-size: var(--h6);
  line-height: calc(var(--h6) * 1.5);
}

.main-header {
  background-color: #3498DB;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 56px;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 12px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.main-header h1 {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: 1.35;
  font-family: "Noto Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
}
.main-header .switch {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.switch {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.current {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  height: 42px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 42px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 0 0.2em 0 0.7em;
}
.current span {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 0.7em 0.2em 0 0;
}
.current .arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
.current:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.options {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0.6em;
  z-index: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.36s ease-out;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.switch.show-options .options {
  display: block;
  z-index: 5;
}
.switch.anim-options .options {
  opacity: 1;
}
.switch.show-shadow .options {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 12px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.options-list {
  color: #313436;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.4rem 0.8em;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}
.options-list li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.75em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E1E4E6;
  transform: translateX(10px);
  transition: all 0.24s ease-out;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.3;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.options-list li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
.options-list li:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
.options-list li:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 0.15s;
}
.options-list li:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.options-list li:nth-child(4) {
  transition-delay: 0.25s;
}
.options-list li:nth-child(5) {
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
.options-list li.selected {
  color: #3498DB;
}
.switch.anim-options .options-list li {
  transform: translateX(0);
  opacity: 1;
}

#trans-circle {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -80px;
  right: -80px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  overflow: hidden;
}
#trans-circle svg {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.switch.anim-options #trans-circle {
  transform: scale(9);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">

<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<header class="main-header">

  <h1 data-lang="en">Language Switch</h1>
  <h1 data-lang="sv">Språkbyte</h1>
  
  <div class="switch">
    <div class="current">
      <span>en</span>
      <em class="arrow"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18"><title>ic_arrow_drop_down_18px</title>
    <g fill="#FFFFFF">
        <path d="M5 8l4 4 4-4z"></path>
    </g>
</svg></em>
    </div>
    <div class="options">
      <ul class="options-list">
        <li data-lang="en">English</li>
        <li data-lang="sv">Svenska</li>
        </ul>
      <div id="trans-circle"> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 120 120"> <g id="circle" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"> <circle id="bg" cx="60" cy="60" r="60" fill="#FFFFFF"/> </g> </svg>
        
    </div>
  </div>
   
</header>
  <main id="content" class="en">
    <h1 data-lang="en">Design</h1>
    <h1 data-lang="sv">konstruktion</h1>
</main>
```

I want the "dropdown Menu" to close when I click anywhere on the page with the mouse?

You can run the "snipper code" in the example by making it full page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve this by adding an event listener to the window object and check if the clicked element is outside the `.switch` element. For that you could give the event to the handler function:

```js
$(window).on('click', function(event) {...});
```

, check with the `is()` function if it or its `parents()` don't have the class `.switch`:

```js
if (!$(event.target).is('.switch') && !$(event.target).parents().is('.switch'))
```

and if true, remove the class `.show-options`:

```js
el.removeClass('show-options');
```

all together:

```js
$(window).on('click', function(event) {
  if (!$(event.target).is('.switch') && !$(event.target).parents().is('.switch')) {
    el.removeClass('show-options');
  }
});
```

**Working example:**

```js
let el = $('.switch');
let cur = el.find('.current');
let options = el.find('.options li');
let content = $('#content');

// Open language dropdown panel
el.on('click', function(e) {
  el.addClass('show-options');
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    el.addClass('anim-options');
  }, 50);
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    el.addClass('show-shadow');
  }, 200);
});

$(window).on('click', function(event) {
  if (!$(event.target).is('.switch') && !$(event.target).parents().is('.switch')) {
    el.removeClass('show-options');
  }
});

// Close language dropdown panel
options.on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  el.removeClass('anim-options');
  el.removeClass('show-shadow');
  
  let newLang = $(this).data('lang');
  
  cur.find('span').text(newLang);
  content.attr('class', newLang);
  
  setLang(newLang);
  
  options.removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    el.removeClass('show-options');
  }, 600);
});

// Save selected options into Local Storage
function getLang() {
  let lang;
  if (localStorage.getItem('currentLang') === null) {
    lang = cur.find('span').text();
  } else {
    lang = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentLang')).toLowerCase();
  }
  
  // console.log(lang);
  cur.find('span').text(lang);
  options.parent().find(`li[data-lang="${lang}"]`).addClass('selected');
  
  content.attr('class', lang);
}

getLang();

function setLang(newLang) {
  localStorage.setItem('currentLang', JSON.stringify(newLang).toLowerCase());
  
  content.attr('class', newLang);
  
  // console.log('New language is: ' + newLang);
}
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,900|Noto+Sans:400,400i,700&subset=latin-ext");
:root {
  font-size: 100%;
  --base-font-size: calc(15px + .5vw);
  --ratio: 1.18;
  --h6: calc(var(--base-font-size) * var(--ratio));
  --h5: calc(var(--h6) * var(--ratio));
  --h4: calc(var(--h5) * var(--ratio));
  --h3: calc(var(--h4) * var(--ratio));
  --h2: calc(var(--h3) * var(--ratio));
  --h1: calc(var(--h2) * var(--ratio));
}

body {
  font-family: "Noto Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-size: var(--base-font-size);
  line-height: 1.6;
  color: #313436;
}

#content {
  max-width: 48rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
}
#content:not(.en) [data-lang=en], #content:not(.sv) [data-lang=sv]{
  display: none;
}
#content.en [data-lang=en],#content.sv [data-lang=sv]{
  display: block;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Playfair Display", "Noto Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: var(--h1);
  line-height: calc(var(--h1) * 1.2);
}

h2 {
  font-size: var(--h2);
  line-height: calc(var(--h2) * 1.2);
}

h3 {
  font-size: var(--h3);
  line-height: calc(var(--h3) * 1.3);
}

h4 {
  font-size: var(--h4);
  line-height: calc(var(--h4) * 1.3);
}

h5 {
  font-size: var(--h5);
  line-height: calc(var(--h5) * 1.4);
}

h6 {
  font-size: var(--h6);
  line-height: calc(var(--h6) * 1.5);
}

.main-header {
  background-color: #3498DB;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 56px;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 12px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.main-header h1 {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: 1.35;
  font-family: "Noto Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
}
.main-header .switch {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.switch {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.current {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  height: 42px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 42px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 0 0.2em 0 0.7em;
}
.current span {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 0.7em 0.2em 0 0;
}
.current .arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
.current:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.options {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0.6em;
  z-index: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.36s ease-out;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.switch.show-options .options {
  display: block;
  z-index: 5;
}
.switch.anim-options .options {
  opacity: 1;
}
.switch.show-shadow .options {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 12px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.options-list {
  color: #313436;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.4rem 0.8em;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}
.options-list li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.75em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E1E4E6;
  transform: translateX(10px);
  transition: all 0.24s ease-out;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.3;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.options-list li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
.options-list li:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
.options-list li:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 0.15s;
}
.options-list li:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.options-list li:nth-child(4) {
  transition-delay: 0.25s;
}
.options-list li:nth-child(5) {
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
.options-list li.selected {
  color: #3498DB;
}
.switch.anim-options .options-list li {
  transform: translateX(0);
  opacity: 1;
}

#trans-circle {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -80px;
  right: -80px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  overflow: hidden;
}
#trans-circle svg {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.switch.anim-options #trans-circle {
  transform: scale(9);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">

<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<header class="main-header">

  <h1 data-lang="en">Language Switch</h1>
  <h1 data-lang="sv">Språkbyte</h1>
  
  <div class="switch">
    <div class="current">
      <span>en</span>
      <em class="arrow"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18"><title>ic_arrow_drop_down_18px</title>
    <g fill="#FFFFFF">
        <path d="M5 8l4 4 4-4z"></path>
    </g>
</svg></em>
    </div>
    <div class="options">
      <ul class="options-list">
        <li data-lang="en">English</li>
        <li data-lang="sv">Svenska</li>
        </ul>
      <div id="trans-circle"> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 120 120"> <g id="circle" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"> <circle id="bg" cx="60" cy="60" r="60" fill="#FFFFFF"/> </g> </svg>
        
    </div>
  </div>
   
</header>
  <main id="content" class="en">
    <h1 data-lang="en">Design</h1>
    <h1 data-lang="sv">konstruktion</h1>
</main>
```